# Javascript : removing new line does not work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been looking around here, tried different things but I just couldn't get it fixed..

```
var save_field = res[0];
var save_value = res[1];
save_value = save_value.replace(/\n/gm, '<br />');
console.log(save_value);

$('#'+save_field).html(save_value);
```

The 'save_value' variable has content like "Klant: Vermaeren B.\nType: Brandstoffilter\nVoertuig: Peugeot 306 1.4i XR". And I want to replace those \n with `<br />` because I show it in a div.. But the \n doesn't get replaced.. :/

I have retrieved the content with a jQuery $.ajax() request. I've also tried to use nl2br() on the result in that ajax file but JavaScript keeps giving me the newline \n..

Can someone help me out please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to escape the "\" before "n" . Try :

```
save_value = save_value.replace(/\\n/gm, '<br />');
```

Comment: Such a little thing that can do a lot..

It worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a literal string `\n` rather than a newline, you'll want to escape the backslash `\\n` - you may also want to check for the return character `\r`or `\\r`

```
save_value = save_value.replace(/(\\r)?\\n/gm,'<br/>');//literal string
```

or

```
save_value = save_value.replace(/\r?\n/gm,'<br/>');//newline characters
```

or for extra inclusion, both!

```
save_value = save_value.replace(/\r?\n/gm,'<br/>').replace(/(\\r)?\\n/gm,'<br/>');
```

Comment: You can use one assignment only, concatenating two `.replace` together

Comment: @LightStyle I know, they're options - use one or the other depending on whether the newlines are literal strings or actual newline characters